# Mac shell script to hide/show hidden files

Tags: macos, shell, automator, hidden-files

I'm very new to mac shell scripting, but I've written this to toggle hide/show hidden  files on mac. (Then put on automator application) Is this a good solution?

```
#!/bin/sh

view=$(defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles)

if [ "$view" = "1" ]
then
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool false
else
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool true
fi
killall Finder
```

Comment: Killing the Finder process is a bit extreme - what happens if the Finder is in the middle of doing something ?

Comment: Probably is a bit extreme, but it's not possible to change from hidden files to shown files (and back) without re-starting finder.

Comment: Well I hope you have back ups !

Comment: You could restart the Finder by logging out using the Apple menu command: "Log Out..." You could check the checkbox: "Reopen windows when logging back in" if you didn't want to lose your place.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a script like this:

```
do shell script "x=$(defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles)
[ $x = 1 ] && b=false || b=true
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool $b"
tell application "Finder"
    quit
    delay 0.1 -- without this there was a "connection is invalid" error
    launch -- without this Finder was not made frontmost
    activate -- make Finder frontmost
    reopen -- open a default window
end tell
```

I don't know if `killall Finder` would be that dangerous either. It sends Finder a TERM signal, which can usually be caught by a process in order to terminate cleanly. Finder doesn't support sudden termination as of 10.8, but if it did, it should be safe to even send it a KILL signal.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a fast way to show/hide hidden files from Terminal in Mac, add the lines below to your `.bash_profile` file in your home directory:

```
alias hidden-files-show="defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES; killall Finder";
alias hidden-files-hide="defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles NO; killall Finder";
```

Close and open a new Terminal window for the new `alias` commands take effect, then you can quickly type "hid"-Tab to auto complete

```
$ hidden-files-show
$ hidden-files-hide
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `killall Finder`, which is somewhat extreme and dangerous (you may kill the Finder in the middle of file copying or other I/O operations). Instead you could just send an AppleEvent to the Finder to tell it to refresh a given window. E.g. to refresh the frontmost window you can do this in AppleScript:

```
tell application "Finder"
  tell front window
    update every item with necessity
  end tell
end tell
```

(from http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2009091413423819)

You can easily adapt this to refresh every open Finder window if that's what you need.

To run AppleScript code such as the above from a bash script you can use the [osascript](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man1/osascript.1.html) command line tool, e.g.

```
osascript <<EOF
tell application "Finder"
  tell front window
    update every item with necessity
  end tell
end tell
EOF
```

Comment: When I tried running `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool true; osascript -e 'tell windows of app "Finder" to update items with necessity'`, hidden files were not shown in Finder. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

This question is old, but here's a good solution using your code:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to quit'
```

It's similar method for closing finder, but is more concise than [Paul R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/253056/paul-r)'s answer. Paul, if you see this and I'm missing any potential issues, *please* let me know.

Alternatively, you could use:

```
STATUS=`defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles`
if [ $STATUS == TRUE ]; 
then
 defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE
else
 defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
fi
osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to quit'
```

Answer (score 1):

For what it is worth, I have the following in my .bash_profile for doing this, similar to  @SwankyLegg

```
togglehidden() {
  STATUS=`defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles`
  if [ $STATUS == TRUE ]; 
  then
    defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE
  else
    defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
  fi
  osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to quit'
  sleep 1
  osascript -e 'launch app "Finder"'
}
```

so I can call it from the Terminal. (NB, if you run it on a machine where `AppleShowAllFiles` has never been set, you'll get a complaint the first time you run it,ala:

```
XXXXXXXXX defaults[2228:124111] 
The domain/default pair of (/Users/xxx/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder, AppleShowAllFiles) does not exist
```

but everything's gonna be OK. I believe that it lives in the `NSGlobalDomain` by default, but this sets it in the user's. )